# VBA comboBox not returning second drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, not really sure what I did wrong but when I run it, it gives me an overflow error.  The drop down list in the first combo Box works fine, but when I select  the "subcat" from the list it gives me the overflow error.

Any clues?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detailed")
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, sh.Range("3:3"), 0)
Me.ComboBox2.Clear
For i = 4 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(3, n).EntireColumn)
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detailed")

Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("3:3"))
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Cells(3, i).Value
    'ComboBox1.Text = "SubCat"
    
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration of i to be of type *Long*, since the number of cells in *EntireColumn* dramatically exceeds the capacity of an *Integer* (the extant type for *i*).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the error procedure `ComboBox1_Change()`:

- Declare all your Integers as Long to avoid an overflow error 6,
  which btw is the typical for cases with row values exceeding the positive integer limit of 32 767.
- Define your data's HeaderRow, e.g. as constant `Const HeaderRow As Long = 3`
- Extend the loop range by adding the number of rows before the HeaderRow, i.e. `HeaderRow - 1`:

```
For i = HeaderRow + 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(HeaderRow, n).EntireColumn) + (HeaderRow - 1)
    ' ...
Next i
```

**Further hints**

Note that the chosen way to count the number of data rows would ignore empty cells, so that I'd prefer something like

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, n).End(xlUp).Row
For i = HeaderRow + 1 To LastRow
    '...
Next i
```

As adding each element one by one can be time-consuming,
I'd prefer to avoid a cellular loop and to write the whole column data to a variant datafield array and
assign them eventually to the combobox'es `.List` property *in one go*.

```
With sh
    Dim data As Variant
    data = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow+1,n),.Cells(LastRow,n)).Value2
    Me.ComboBox1.List = data
End With
```

which could be shortened even to

```
With sh
    Me.ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow+1,n),.Cells(LastRow,n)).Value2
End With
```